# What changed between the original and the revised editions of Universalis?

Tags: edition-comparison, universalis

I've played quite a bit of the original version but I'm skeptical about buying an updated copy.

I know there is a change to the way ties are resolved during a Complication, but I don't know the details.  How does that work now?  What else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoting from the Forge](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=19960.0):

> Edge Dice are in the game but the
>   crazy math part is gone.  Now, if you
>   roll a tie in a Complication, whoever
>   had the highest sum adds an Edge Die
>   to their pool and you reroll.  For
>   purposes of determining Bonus Coins
>   the Edge Die counts just like a
>   regular die instead of adding its
>   total seperately.
>
> That's the only real rule change, per
>   se.
>
> I did completely rewrite the
>   Complications chapter to tighten down
>   how things actually get done in a
>   complication and make it more in line
>   with how I actually play it.  Whether
>   or not that will seem like a rules
>   change depends on how closely your
>   style of running Complications matched
>   mine.
>
> The art is unchanged, so yep the
>   Slytheran Doom Cannon are still on
>   their way to visit some whoop ass on
>   Meadow village.